# What is the best ways to set up different environment variables for NativeScript with Angular?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In Angular, the the de facto way to load env vars into the app is using `environment.ts` which is part of the cli.

In NativeScript, it seems like that doesn't work with the NativeScript cli.

What's the best way to do so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Updated 8/25/2018

If you're using [webpack](https://docs.nativescript.org/performance-optimizations/bundling-with-webpack) with NativeScript, you can pass environment variables into webpack which you can then access from your code. When you install NativeScript webpack for the first time, it will generate a webpack.config.js in the same folder that your package.json is in. Open webpack.config.js in a code editor and search for `new webpack.DefinePlugin` and modify it like so:

```
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
            'process.env': {
                'envtype': JSON.stringify(env && env.envtype ? env.envtype : ""),
                'gmapsKey': JSON.stringify(env && env.gmapsKey ? env.gmapsKey : ""),
                'stripeKey': JSON.stringify(env && env.stripeKey ? env.stripeKey : ""),
                // etc, these are just examples
            }
        }),
```

Then, inject your environment variables during build:

```
// for example
tns run android --bundle --env.envtype="dev" --env.gmapsKey="KEY_HERE" --env.stripeKey="KEY_HERE"
```

Then, you can access your environment variables in-code like so:

## With Angular

You can create an Angular service and access your injected variables in any component you want.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var process: any;

@Injectable()
export class EnvironmentManagerService {
    private getEnvironmentVars(key: string): string {
        if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) {
            return process.env[key];
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public getGoogleMapsKey(): string {
        return this.getEnvironmentVars("gmapsKey");
    }

    public getStripePublishableKey(): string {
        return this.getEnvironmentVars("stripeKey");
    }

    public isDev(): boolean {
        return this.getEnvironmentVars("envtype") === "dev";
    }
}
```

## Without Angular

Create a new file in your project under your app folder. You can call the file anything you want. Add the following:

```
declare var process: any;

export function getEnvironmentVars(key: string): string {
    if (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) {
        return process.env[key];
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

You can import that file from anywhere with `import * as env from '<file path here>'` and call `env.getEnvironmentVars(...)`, e.g. `env.getEnvironmentVars("gmapsKey")`.

---

There might also be ways to simulate the same environment.ts and environment.prod.ts approach by conditionally modifying the files that webpack includes, but I didn't explore that approach as the above was sufficient for my purposes.

If you aren't using webpack, you can use the [custom hooks](https://blog.davincisoftware.sk/building-a-mobile-nativescript-app) approach, although I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this and report back. My team said Webpack was  a pain to setup / learn before. It seems from your response it's not that much effort.

Comment: It sure can be depending on the codebase that you're working on -- sometimes it's easy, other times you'll be googling why your code doesn't compile when bundling is enabled.

Comment: Is it possible to get these variable values from build.xconfig instead of CLI parameters?

Comment: I don't see why not. Before you define the plugin, you can read your xconfig file -- it's just Nodejs. There's probably an npm module somewhere out there for it too.

Answer (score 0):

The following by default is set in the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'global.TNS_WEBPACK': 'true',
    TNS_ENV: JSON.stringify(mode),
    process: 'global.process'
}),
```

The `mode` variable is taken from the following code in the `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const mode = production ? 'production' : 'development';
```

To set the `production` variable in webpack.config.js you must set the `--release` flag when building/running. `https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/run.html` states:

> --release - If set, produces a release build by running webpack in production mode and native build in release mode. Otherwise, produces
> a debug build.

This means to test "production mode" locally without building a release .apk file, you must do what arao6 said.