# Environment variables using in Nativescript with Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular2-nativescript

I want to use the environment data in my native script with Angular application. I face the below error as "**ReferenceError: process is not defined**".

**Run the application**

```
 npm run android --env.apiUrl="https://******.com/" --env.apiUserName="****" --env.apiPassword="*******"
```

**Angular service**

```
    import { } from 'node';
declare var process: any;

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {
  apiUrl: string;
  userName: string;
  password: string;
  platform: string;

  constructor ()  {


    this.apiUrl = (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) ? process.env['apiUrl'] : '';
    this.userName = (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) ? process.env['apiUserName'] : '';
    this.password = (typeof process !== 'undefined' && process && process.env) ? process.env['apiPassword'] : '';
    console.log('API URL-->' + this.apiUrl);
    console.log('API USERNAME-->' + this.userName);
    console.log('API PASSWORD-->' + this.password);
    console.log(process.env);

    if (isAndroid) {
        this.platform = 'android';
    } else if (isIOS) {
        this.platform = 'ios';
    }
  }
```

I am not able to take the apiuRL , apiUserName and apiPassword which I have passed when running the application as the environment. I have referred the below StackOverflow question. But, unlucky. Anybody help me how to take those data from the environment.

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450230/what-is-the-best-ways-to-set-up-different-environment-variables-for-nativescript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a nativescript developer but i know Angular way to do this.

You can use `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts`, where you put all the environment related variables like apiUserName and apiUrl .. etc.

In your service you should import the environment and use it in typescript normal way.

For more details check the following link: https://alligator.io/angular/environment-variables/

Hope this will inspire you and solve your problem.

**Update**

If you are using webpack you can access `process.env` in your webpack configuration.

```
modules.exports = (env) => {
    let apiUrl = env.apiUrl;
    return {
        entry: '', 
        ......
    }
}
```

Now once you have access your `env` in the webpack configuration, you have many choices to pass them to an angular application.

1. Use `webpack.DefinePlugin` (recommended). https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/386
2. Use `fs` to write on json file and then read from it in angular application using http.

Comment: Thats ok, but I want to use process.env. Anyidea about that

Comment: You don't have access to process.env in Angular applicatoin. it is only available to you in Node.js application.

Comment: Okay i just saw your updated question ...Are you using webpack ??

Comment: Yes. I use webpack

Comment: Hi Nour, This is my webconfig new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "global.TNS_WEBPACK": "true",
                'process.env': {
                    'apiUrl': JSON.stringify(env && env.envtype ? env.envtype : ""),
                    'apiUserName': JSON.stringify(env && env.gmapsKey ? env.gmapsKey : ""),
                    'apiPassword': JSON.stringify(env && env.stripeKey ? env.stripeKey : ""),
                    // etc, these are just examples
                }
            }),